# how to find rows which have specific column value which is entered in textbox in data table?

Tags: c#

I have a data table(dt) with column names firstname, lastname, companymname and emailId. This data table have N number of rows.

Now user enter his/her emailId in text box and I have the value as emailaddress in my class function in C#.

I have to compare the emailaddress value to emailID column values one by one and if value matches I have return the entire matched row in viewbag to UI.

```
var dt = ExcelDataToDataTable(fileName, "Sheet1");
var emailaddress = emailaddress ;
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("Email = emailaddress");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dt = ExcelDataToDataTable(fileName, "Sheet1");
var emailaddress = "user@example.com"; // Replace this with the actual email address
string filterExpression = $"emailId = '{emailaddress}'";
DataRow[] result = dt.Select(filterExpression);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be something like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("firstname");
dt.Columns.Add("lastname");
dt.Columns.Add("companyname");
dt.Columns.Add("emailId");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["firstname"] = "FirstName" + i;
 dr["lastname"] = "LastName" + i;
 dr["companyname"] = "Company" + i;
 dr["emailId"] = "Email" + i;
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);}

 var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("emailId") == "Email3").ToArray();
```